# How to display error messsages in visualforce Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

> Kindly let me know how to add error messages on the below Apex method. if non >numeric values are entered in the Square Footage and Price Fields.Currently >variables >for the fields are String type.

```
public void  Search(){
  string searchquery= 'select        name,Beds__c,Square_Footage__c,Initial_List_Price__c,Status__c from Condo__c        where name!=null and Status__c in (\'Available\',\'Unsold\') ';


        if (beds >= '0')
           searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+'';

        if (SFminimum > '0' && SFmaximum > '0') 
           searchquery+= ' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFminimum+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmaximum+' ';

        if (ILPminimum >'0' && ILPmaximum > '0')
           searchquery += 'and Initial_List_Price__c >= '+ILPminimum+' and Initial_List_Price__c <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';


        if (beds >= '0' && SFminimum > '0' && SFmaximum > '0')
           searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFminimum+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmaximum+' '; 

         if (beds >= '0' && ILPminimum > '0' && ILPmaximum > '0')

             searchquery += 'and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Initial_List_Price__c >= '+ILPminimum+' and Initial_List_Price__c <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';

          if(beds >= '0' && SFminimum > '0' && SFmaximum > '0' && ILPminimum > '0' && ILPmaximum > '0')

             searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFminimum+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmaximum+' and Initial_List_Price__c >= '+ILPminimum+' and Initial_List_Price__c <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';

         if(beds >= '0' && SFminimum > '0')

              searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c  >= '+SFminimum+' ';

          if(beds >= '0' && SFmaximum > '0')

              searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c  <= '+SFmaximum+' ';

          if(beds >= '0' && ILPminimum > '0')

             searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Initial_List_Price__c  >= '+ILPminimum+' ';

           if(beds >= '0' && ILPmaximum > '0')

             searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Initial_List_Price__c  <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';

           if(SFminimum > '0')

              searchquery += ' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFminimum+' ';

            if(SFmaximum > '0')

              searchquery += ' and Square_Footage__c  <= '+SFmaximum+' ';

             if( ILPminimum > '0')

               searchquery += ' and Initial_List_Price__c  >= '+ILPminimum+' ';

             if(ILPmaximum > '0')

             searchquery += ' and Initial_List_Price__c  <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';

 cond = Database.query(searchquery);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you might need to change your code 

`"beds >= '0'".`

This will do a string comparson. Instead you might try like

`Integer.valueOf(beds) > 0`.

Add for showing error message on VF page, you can use  `<apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>` in your VF page and in the controller method  write like;

`if(Integer.valueOf(beds) <= 0)
{
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter number greater then 0'));
return null;
}`

Edit:

To ensure your text fields have only number entered, you can try like;

```
try
{
 Integer.valueOf(SFminimum);
 Integer.valueOf(SFmaximum);
 Integer.valueOf(ILPminimum);
 Integer.valueOf(ILPmaximum);
}
catch(TypeException te)
{
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter numbers only'));
return null;
}
```

Put this in the beginning of search() method.

Comment: beds field is a dropdown list on vf page

Comment: i want to check only numbers are entered in Square Footage and Price Fields. i have added a screen shot for reference.

Comment: Still you should convert if you want an integer comparison. e.g. ('2' > '19') this will give you true where 2 > 19 is false.

Comment: @chaitanya check the portion after "Edit". Hope it might help you. But my suggestion will be, do not do string comparison on number.

Comment: i tried your suggestion. i have kept the method in the begining of search method. but it is displaying only the message when i try to search records.

Comment: I did not get you @chaitanya. If you give anything other than number in these four inputs, then it will show the message. otherwise your code will execute.

Comment: kindly let me know where to place your code in my search method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38384/discussion-between-saumya-ranjan-satapathy-and-chaitanya).

Comment: just put it before
string searchquery= 'select name,Beds__c,Square_Footage__c,Initial_List_Price__c,Status__c from Condo__c where name!=null and Status__c in (\'Available\',\'Unsold\') ';

Comment: If its still not wrking for you, then update you question with what is coming on you vf page and your search method.